# SharePoint Search Express 2010 return results only if anonymous is allowed

Tags: search, anonymous-authentication

I have a problem: in my current SSE 2010 I'm using a domain user account with read only rights in every web app to do the crawling. Log files show no problem, everything is indexed ok. Problem is that I dont get any results on any Search Page, no matter what user I'm using unless **I do enable anonymous acces on site collection and then do a recrawl**. What could be the issue ? I don't wanna allow anonymous access for this.

Many thanx,

Answer (score 1):

The crawl account probably doesn't have sufficient permission to retrieve the ACLs for the users, so the index (or rather the property store) doesn't contain this information. Try giving your crawl account greater privileges or put it in the same group as your users.